# Can't get the actual height of a div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to get the actual of height of a div, but all of the jquery functions below produce the same value which is shorter than the actual height by about 10 pixels. I confirmed the actual height using a screen capture and measuring it in photoshop.

What method(s) are needed to get the correct height?

```
alert($("#content-container").outerHeight(true));
alert($("#content-container").outerHeight());
alert($("#content-container").height());

#content-container {
width: 970px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
height: auto;
min-height: 550px;
}

<body>
<div id="content-container">Content</div>
</body>
```

There is content in the div but too much to post here. I want the total height of the container such that if I applied a border to it you could measure from the top edge of the border to the bottom edge of the border. Right now the height I'm getting is 10 pixel less than that measurement.

Comment: If you are using firexfox and have firebug go to HTML Tab > Layout window... there you would get your answer.

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS as well was what you expect to get and what you actually get.

Comment: Please define what YOU mean by "actual height".

Comment: What is in the `#content-container`? If you have content that is dynamically added, modified or removed by JS after the height is alerted, the final, actual height of the element will be different from the one fetched by JS.

Comment: If you have floating elements within the div, that may distort the actual height. Use a clear-fix solution for floating elements to force your div to the actual height. In other words, yes, your Content is important to understanding the problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll check into that further. I do have floats and a clear fix, but it appears to coded correctly.

Answer (score 3):

> OuterHeight gives you the height with padding and margin applied on
>   the content-container, innerHeight gives you the height with padding
>   only while height gives you the height excluding padding and margin
>   applied on the content-container.

And you want to know the total height. Its better you use outerHeight()

```
alert($("#content-container").outerHeight());
```

**Moreover you want to solve your question, the better for you to post your fiddle. Thank you dear.**

Comment: I tried that, but apparently there are ways to alter the height without jQuery being to detect it.

Answer (score 1):

The div may need to have an explicit height set, it won't return what the height is otherwise.

Comment: This is only partially true. If the div is fully block level and all child elements are also block level, then the correct height should be easily attainable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be related to an unordered list that is in the content area. I wanted the items to display inline and set the li to display:inline, when I removed the inline property and changed it to float:left it started working. This makes no sense to me, but it does work now.